# Progress Bar Not Aligning Vertically

Tags: html, css

The [First] step in the progress bar is not aligning with step [Two, Three, and Four]. See picture below:

[image: problem image]

There is a couple pixel space between the top of steps 2,3, and 4 and I am not sure how to fix? The code works perfectly in the insert, but on my webpage it is not working. Perhaps there is css overlap? I even changed the div classes to something very unique and it wasn't fixing it.

I put a red line on top of the progress bar to emphasize the small space error. **In sum, the circle for the first step is a couple pixels higher than the rest... I need to figure out a way to fix this.**

My code is below:

```css
.containerpb { 
    width: 100%;
    margin: 50px auto;
  }
.progressbar {
      counter-reset: step;
      border-top: 1px solid red;
  }
  .progressbar li {
      list-style-type: none;
      width: 25%;
      float: left;
      font-size: 12px;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #7d7d7d;
  }
  .progressbar li:before {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      content: counter(step);
      counter-increment: step;
      line-height: 30px;
      border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: white;
  }
  .progressbar li:after {
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #7d7d7d;
      top: 15px;
      left: -50%;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  .progressbar li:first-child:after {
      content: none;
  }
  .progressbar li.active {
      color: green;
  }
  .progressbar li.active:before {
      border-color: #55b776;
  }
  .progressbar li.active + li:after {
      background-color: #55b776;
  }
```

```html
<div class="containerpb">
<ul class="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Complete Basic Information</li>
    <li>Add Secondary Owner(s)</li>
    <li>Review</li>
    <li>Export</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Everything is perfectly touching the line on my screen though. You might want to specify your environment

Comment: I suspect this is an issue with other CSS included on the page because this works for me the way you intended it.  In order to find out where the css collide is, check using devtools and inspect the `li`s that are out of place - it will show you what is causing the gap directly.

Comment: @TammyShipps how do I specify environment? This is within a database management system and I am doing custom css on top of an already existing css book. Then calling the html via the web interface

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Thanks for everyone's help. It was a margin-top id for the li+li content. Had to change it from .25em to 0. Thanks!

Comment: You can just add this as a comment to the question or simply delete the question, since problems like this isn't likely to help anyone in future